# Passing data to a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist

I am trying to pass "personListToPrint" to main.java and have it come up when switch 3 is used, however it will not work. I am not sure how to go about fixing this. Any ideas??

here is main.java

```
package hartman;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Printer.printWelcome();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean keepRunning = true;
    while (keepRunning) {
        Printer.printMenu();
        Printer.printPrompt("Please enter your operation: ");

        String userSelection = keyboard.nextLine();

        switch (userSelection) {
        case "1":
            Database.addPerson(personList);
            break;
        case "2":
            Database.printDatabase(personList);
            break;
        case "3":
            Printer.printSearchPersonTitle();
            String searchFor = keyboard.nextLine();
            Database.findPerson(searchFor);
            Printer.printPersonList(personListToPrint);
            break;
        case "4":
            keepRunning = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    Printer.printGoodBye();
    keyboard.close();
  }

 }
```

and here is database.java

```
package hartman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Database {
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
private static ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

public Database() {

}

public static void addPerson(ArrayList<Person> personList) {
    Printer.printAddPersonTitle();
    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter first name: ");
    String addFirstName = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter last Name: ");
    String addLastName = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter social Security Number: ");
    String addSocial = keyboard.nextLine();

    Printer.printPrompt("  Enter year of birth: ");
    int addYearBorn = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());

    System.out.printf("\n%s, %s saved!\n", addFirstName, addLastName);
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstName(addFirstName);
    person.setLastName(addLastName);
    person.setSocialSecurityNumber(addSocial);
    person.setYearBorn(addYearBorn);
    personList.add(person);
}

public static void printDatabase(ArrayList<Person> personList) {
    System.out
            .printf("\nLast Name           First Name           Social Security Number  Age\n");
    System.out
            .printf("=================== ===================  ======================  ===\n");
    for (Person p : personList) {

        System.out.printf("%-20s%-21s%-24s%s\n", p.getLastName(),
                p.getLastName(), p.getSocialSecurityNumber(), p.getAge());

    }

}

public static ArrayList<Person> findPerson(String searchFor) {
    ArrayList<Person> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person p : personList) {
        boolean isAMatch = false;

        if (p.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        }
        if (p.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;

        }
        if (p.getSocialSecurityNumber().contains(searchFor)) {
            isAMatch = true;
            ;
        } else if (String.format("%d", p.getAge()).equals(searchFor))
            if (isAMatch) {

            }
        matches.add(p);
        Printer.printPersonList(matches);
    }
    return matches;

}

}
```

and last, here is printer.java

```
package hartman;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Printer {
public static void printWelcome() {
    System.out.printf("WELCOME TO PERSON DATABASE!\n");
}

public static void printGoodBye() {
    System.out.printf("\nGOOD BYE!!\n");
}

public static void printMenu() {
    System.out.printf("\nMain Menu\n");
    System.out.printf("---------\n\n");
    System.out.printf("  1. Add a new Person to the database.\n");
    System.out.printf("  2. Print the database.\n");
    System.out.printf("  3. Search for a person in the database.\n");
    System.out.printf("  4. Exit the application.\n");
    System.out.printf("\n");
}

public static void printPrintMenu() {
    System.out.printf("Print\n\n");
}

public static void printAddPersonTitle() {
    System.out.printf("\nAdd Person to Database\n\n");

}

public static void printPrompt(String promptForWhat) {
    System.out.printf("%s", promptForWhat);
}

public static void printPersonSaved(Person personSaved) {
    System.out.printf("%s", personSaved);
}

public static void printSearchPersonTitle() {
    System.out.printf("\nSearch for Person in Database\n\n");
    System.out.printf("Enter search value: ");
}

public static void printPersonList(ArrayList<Person> personListToPrint) {

    System.out
            .printf("\nLast Name           First Name           Social Security Number  Age\n");
    System.out
            .printf("=================== ===================  ======================  ===\n");
    for (Person p : personListToPrint) {

        System.out.printf("%-20s%-21s%-24s%s\n", p.getLastName(),
                p.getLastName(), p.getSocialSecurityNumber(), p.getAge());

    }

}
}
```

Comment: `personListToPrint` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. How are you passing it in?

Comment: i am not sure, could you maybe give me a hint or assistance? :)

Comment: Well, personListToPrint needs to be defined somewhere and you need to populate it with data somehow.

Comment: I think you just need to pass personList to printPersonList.  Like so, printPersonList(personList).

Comment: matches in database, are passed to printer.printPersonList. That data then needs to be passed to main.java for it to work in the switch.

Answer (score 1):

You did not define variable

> personListToPrint

Replace case 3 with next

```
case "3":
    Printer.printSearchPersonTitle();
    String searchFor = keyboard.nextLine();
    ArrayList<Person> personListToPrint = Database.findPerson(searchFor);
    Printer.printPersonList(personListToPrint);
    break;
```

Now is compilable

Comment: Updated, try now - List replaced with ArrayList

Comment: This is correct. The info I gave you is factual, but I missed the detail that findPerson returned the list you are in fact wanting to print. Good catch @aleks.n.fedorov!

Comment: When a search is run using case 3, nothing is returned. It displays no results.

Answer (score 0):

```
Printer.printPersonList(personListToPrint);
```

Where is it supposed to come from? personListToPrint is never defined anywhere. (I Ctrl-F searched your code samples and it's nowhere)

Comment: Matches in database is passed to Printer.printPersonList(matches);
It then is run through an if statement to run a search, the results should be passed to main.java in switch 3 to display search results.

Comment: personListToPrint is a formal parameter in his Printer class. I believe the OP is confused about formal vs actual parameter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

your calling printer directly without having created an object of the class.

```
Printer printerObj = new Printer();
```

Comment: His entire Printer class is statically defined, so no, you don't need to instantiate an object to use the class the way the OP has it built.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have your confusion figured out, but explaining it is a tad tricky.

In your Printer class, you have the following method declaration:

```
public static void printPersonList(ArrayList<Person> personListToPrint)
```

In this case, personListToPrint is the name of the variable you'll use INSIDE this method to refer to the ACTUAL ArrayList that is passed to the method when it's called from the external source.

In your case, you are calling it using this invocation within your Case "3" block:

```
    Printer.printPersonList(personListToPrint);
```

Even though the method calls it "personListToPrint," when you make the above call, you really want to pass in personList. Within Main, personList refers to some ArrayList, let's say at some memory location defined as "0100." When Printer.printPersonList is invoked, you want to pass in the array list you want printed, in this case personList (residing at memory "0100").  Once inside of printPersonList, the ArrayList stored at "0100" will be referred to using the variable name personListToPrint. It's two different names for the same memory location.

The other person who commented about the fact that you never declared or instantiated personListToPrint is right, so when you call printPersonList(personListToPrint) the way you are doing now, you're passing in a null since that particular variable was never declared or instantiated (you should actually get a compile error).

If this is confusing, comment back and I'll try to explain in a different way.